# Find all objects in a has_one/belongs_to model association where no association exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two models, `Computer` and `Ipv6Address`

```
Computer belongs_to Ipv6Address
Ipv6Address has_one Computer
```

Using ActiveRecord, how can I find a list of all `Ipv6Addresses` where no `Computer` is associated with it?

Comment: Care to give an example of what that might look like?

Comment: I'm still trying various options, haven't gotten anything to work yet.

Comment: try my edited version that works....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ipv6address_id is foreign key in Computer table

and

id is PK of Ipv6Address_id table

```
ids=Computer.select('Ipv6Address_id')
Ipv6Address.select('*').where('id not in (?)',ids)
```

This may work

Comment: While not exactly what I needed to do, this certainly got me most of the way there. My solution:

`ids = Computer.select('ipv6_address_id').where('ipv6_address_id IS NOT NULL')`
`Ipv6Address.where("id NOT IN (?)", ids.map{ |i| i.ipv6_address_id})`

Answer (score 0):

```
Ipv6Address.where('ipv6address_id = ?', nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using my [Where Exists](https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists) gem:

```
# fast
Ipv6Addresses.where_not_exists(:computer)
```

Benchmark shows it to be much faster in most cases than fetching array of IDs to Ruby and sending it back to the database:

```
# slow
ids = Computer.distinct(:ipv6_address_id).map(&:ipv6_address_id)
Ipv6Address.where.not(id: ids)
```